# Why isn't cluster-SSH working on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 10.04, server, ssh, xterm

I have installed cluster-SSH on my **ubuntu 10.04 server**, it has a dependency of xterm_261-1_amd64. 
when i try to 
`$cssh localhost`
it says

```
ocpe@blrkec241933d:~$ cssh localhost
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
```

and when i try to open xterm it says.

```
ocpe@blrkec241933d:~$ xtermconnect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory

xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Is it coz ubuntu server does not have any UI???? . I just log into it through putty from my windows machine and work.
i dont have any idea, if at all i can fix it.. plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: the problem is your Ubuntu Server doesn't have a GUI (or specifically, an X server)

Cluster-SSH is designed to use multiple xterms, which is only possible if an X server is running locally; if you are running cluster-SSH *over SSH itself*, then you'd need X forwarding enabled.

Setting up an X server in Windows isn't easy, and in any case, cluster-SSH with its multiple terminals wouldn't be very responsive if forwarded over the Internet.

Comment: is'nt there any other way or any other tool, so that i can run commands parallely  on multiple ubuntu systems, with very less time skew!!

Comment: You mean a tool that will run *from Windows*?

Comment: i just want  a tool, whether its on windows or on my ubuntu system. It should just be able to run commands in parallel on multiple systems.
Only one system with ubuntu GUI is enough to use cluster-ssh, or will it work only when all the system in cluster has a GUI!!?

Answer (score 0):

you must set `X11Forwarding` to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the machine to which you are ssh'ing.

Restart **sshd** after setting the above.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thnx, for ur help. X11Forwarding is already set to yes, and its giving the same error.